# cd to my folders shows me an error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line

I just logged out my system and logged on. And i tried to get into my folder

```
cd /u/folder
```

It says

```
Too many levels of symbolic links.
```

But it worked yesterday. What could be the reason? I found many SO questions on this but they are all about creating symlinks. But i face this problem while cd into that directory and ls also showing this error.

Please let me know how to over come this.

```
cd /u works fine.
```

Comment: What do these commands show you: `cd /u ; ls -ld folder` and `cd /u ; ls -ld vijay1`. Is `/u` a symbolic link? `ls -ld /u`

Comment: No /u is not a symbolic link

Comment: Can you paste the output of `stat /u/folder` ?

Comment: Gops, what do the commands that I asked for show?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Mar  4 04:08 .` this is the output. I guess some other problem may cause this issue

Comment: Well, this was not what I have been asking. Nevermind. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Too many levels of symbolic links.

That most likely means that you have a circular symlink.

For example, let's create `folder` which links to itself:

```
$ ln -s folder folder
```

Now, let's `cd` on it:

```
$ cd folder
bash: cd: folder: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

`ls` gives a similar result:

```
$ ls folder
ls: cannot access folder: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

The solution is to examine your `folder` directory and fix whatever circular link that you have.  To help try running `ls -ld` on it:

```
$ ls -ld folder
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 6 Mar  2 21:25 folder -> folder
```

The above clearly shows a simple circular link.

Comment: Thanks John. `ls -ld /u/vijay1  #END#
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Mar  2 00:47 /u/vijay1
#END#[root@scspr0024030001 u]# cd /u/vijay1 #END#
-bash: cd: /u/vijay1: Too many levels of symbolic links` This is i am getting. I don't see any `->` in my directory

Comment: @GopsAB  OK.  Try `find -L /u -mindepth 10`

Comment: Yes John, `find: ‘/u/vijay1’: Too many levels of symbolic links` This is i am getting

Comment: @GopsAB Looking again at your `ls` output, it appears that `vijay1` is a _directory_ of size _zero_ bytes.  That is strange.  On typical linux filesystems, a directory, even if empty, is at least 4096 bytes.  Are you using a filesystem other than ext2/ext3?  Have you tried doing an `fsck` (`e2fsck`) on the filesystem?

Comment: Hi John, I am completely new to unix. I din't try fsck and all. I don't understand what is ext2/ext3.

Comment: @GopsAB My sympathies that a person new to unix has such a strange problem.  Regarding ext2/ext3 etc., there are various ways to organize data on a disk.  They are called _filesystems_.  MS DOS used FAT.  Modern Windows uses NTFS.  Linux offers many with the most common being ext3.  One can verify that a filesystem is in good health by running a File System ChecK ("fsck").  [Here are some instructions for doing that on Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SystemAdministration/Fsck)  It is also possible that other contributors here may have more ideas for things for you to try.